# Many to many - non identifying relationship Data model

Tags: model, many-to-many

We have a small **SQL SERVER 2000** database for importing - trading goods and extending new features to it. I have confusion to implement the right PK - FK Relationship.

There are three tables we have:

```
Contract (ContractID (PK), SupplierID (FK), ProductID(FK), Date, Quantity, Price )

SupplierInvoice ( SupplierInvoiceID (PK), ContractID (FK) , ImportID (FK) , InvoiceNo, Date,Quantity )

Import ( ImportID (PK) , Date )

Truck ( TruckID (PK), ImportID (FK), CustomerID (FK), Date, Quantity)
```

Explanation :

These are bulk products and there are no packaging , but just quantities.

- All PK's are surrogate (auto-incremental)
- With one contract we can have 0 to many invoices and one invoice can be belong to just one contract. 
  ( 0 invoices is going to be 1 in a few days)
- With one to many invoices you make 0 to 1 import. 
  (0 imports is going to be 1 and only one in a few days)
  (many invoices means there can be partial contracts ending and beginning.)
- Quantities : Total Invoice quantity for one contract cannot exceed the contract quantity. We build trigger to control this. Import Quantity is exactly the same as Invoice Quantity.

Questions :

1. Is this model (PK and FK's) in the right way)? What do you think?
2. After importing we load the goods to trucks what we have imported, so we should enter
   which product from which supplier we want to load. If we start to make the `JOIN` query
   from Truck Table to Contract Table until we get the `ProductID` and `SupplierID` then 
   it is a very long query. What do you think?
3. What do you think about the quantity control? Inventory is calculated with calculated 
   field on reports.

Questions 1 and 2 are very important for us to move further. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you only have one product per contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you need to alter the relationship between your invoice and import tables ("With one to many invoices you make 0 to 1 import").  You have your import id as a FK in your invoice table, but I'm pretty sure that what you actually want is a many-to-many relationship with a join table between the invoices and imports so that you can associate many invoices per import.

Also, if you can have more than one product per Contract, you will need a join table between your contract and product tables, in order to allow you to create many-to-many relations between products and contracts.  In other words, I presume that you use the same products for multiple contracts, and that at least some of those contracts might involve more than one product?

I wouldn't worry too much about a few joins.  If you get to where you're joining a dozen tables or something, then before I looked at denormalizing the schema, I would look at creating a strategic view or two in order to simplify the queries.

If you're worried about join *performance* (don't, with this few tables), you can do a lot of index tuning with SQL Server.  You can put indexes on database views.  SQL Server 2000 also supports materialized views, which basically instruct SQL Server to build (and dynamically maintain) a table in the shape of the view so that the joins in the view definition do not have to be performed in real time for every query you perform.  You can also create updateable views, and you can put a subset of database triggers on views.  So I would stick with a well-normalized schema for the sake of data integrity.  I think there are plenty of solutions to address query complexity and join performance issues.

**EDIT:** This is an updated example ER diagram showing the many-to-many relationships between both contracts and products, and between invoices and imports.

[image: Schema showing many-to-many relations between contracts and products, and between invoices and imports]

Comment: Many thanks Craig. Although there is just one product per contract (always) , I can easily remove the many to many over there. Also I shoukd remove join table of supplierinvoice_import, because there are no invoices with many imports. In the meantime, I have seen your previous reply(before you edit) on my phone.I think it better suits my needs. But this one is clear enough , so I'm going to choose supplierinvoiceID as FK for Import table.

Comment: I'm glad this helped.  As to my edit, when I re-read your question this morning it struck me differently and I thought I might have gotten your assumptions wrong, thus the change to many-to-many for the invoices to import table.  Again, I'm glad I was able to help out.